# Decrypt a File take too long to complete using AES

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes

I want to decrypt a PDF file using AES and Key, IV
The size of the file is about 90 MB and may be up to 200 MB.
I use the following codes for decoding and it takes a little time and takes more than 20 seconds, while the codes written in Java and Android immediately decode the file.

```
var key = Convert.FromBase64String("...");
var iv = Convert.FromBase64String("...");

using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
{
    aesAlg.Key = key;
    aesAlg.IV = iv;

    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);


    using (FileStream encryptedStream = new FileStream(encryptedFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, bufferSize: 8192, useAsync: true))
    using (FileStream decryptedStream = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 8192, useAsync: true))
    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // Adjust buffer size as needed
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = await csDecrypt.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            await decryptedStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

how i can decode file fast as possible?

Comment: Algorithmically, all are doing the same. So I would _guess_ your Java implementation does something else differently. Maybe buffer size, maybe file I/O? Did you profile that code to see what time is spent on the most?

Comment: As of Net 6 you might use [CopyToAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.copytoasync?view=net-7.0). A bit more optimized but does not do something completely different then you do now.

Comment: Do you really need useAsync here?

Comment: How about using a larger buffer?

Comment: "Java and Android" or "Java on Android"? AES could be hardware-accelerated on an ARM CPU, I'm not sure if c# has implemented this. Have you tried the java program on the same system as the c# runs (and make sure both are built in release mode)?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed issue with this code:

```
using Aes aes = Aes.Create();
aes.Key = key;
aes.IV = iv;

byte[] encryptedData = File.ReadAllBytes(encryptedFilePath);

using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
{
    await cs.WriteAsync(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
    await cs.FlushFinalBlockAsync();
}

byte[] decryptedData = ms.ToArray();
await File.WriteAllBytesAsync(outputFile, decryptedData);
```

Comment: So, in other words: It's faster to do File I/O in one go, do the crypto and write in one go, than streaming chunks? Is that your finding?

Comment: @Fildor i found codes here: https://getblogyou.blogspot.com/2023/07/how-to-decrypt-aes-encrypted-file-in-csharp.html